# Add other metrics to compute performance

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I use TFF version 0.12.0
In order to compute performance of model, I would like to add (with accuracy ) sensitivity and specificity metrics,

```
def specificity
...
def create_compiled_keras_model():
    ....

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum =0.9), 
             loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=([tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()], sensitivity, specificity))
    return model
```

I found this error:

```
TypeError: Type of `metrics` argument not understood. Expected a list or dictionary, found: ([<tensorflow.python.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy object at 0x7fb5b0711748>], <function sensitivity at 0x7fb6adf45e18>, <function specificity at 0x7fb5fdaf5f28>)
```

So how can I add metrics  in Tensorflow federated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TFF requires metrics to be implemented using the [`tf.keras.metrics.Metric`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric) interface, and can't wrap arbitrary Python functions.

An example of making a custom metric based off of the `tf.keras.metrics.Sum` subclass can be found in https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/3ed93c8036501fe327ede249a4b0f20d02c6f476/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils_test.py#L33. The key being the implementation of `update_state` method.

For sensitivity and specificity metrics, looking at the implementation of [`tf.keras.metrics.SensitivityAtSpecificity`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/582c8d236cb079023657287c318ff26adb239002/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L1531-L1604) and it's base class [`tf.keras.metrics.SensitivitySpecificityBase`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/582c8d236cb079023657287c318ff26adb239002/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L1439) might be useful examples.

Comment: Thanks @Zachary for your answer. Are these metrics for only binary class mode dataset ? If I have a dataset with more than 2 class, I can use those metrics?

Comment: I don't think these metrics would be applicable for a non-binary predictions. It may be possible to create one metric per label? e.g. for a prediction, take each label `K`and compute a `K` vs `not-K` and measure the model performance?

Comment: I find this :`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'specificity'` when I write :`metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SpecificityAtSensitivity()])

Comment: Yes, it appears the constructor requires an additional argument to construct, the documentation is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/SpecificityAtSensitivity. However, the answer points to them as an example of how to subclass, its not clear from the question whether the metric is directly applicable.